# Detect if new window if opend using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Creating a small chat application where user can start chat by clicking on chat button next to user's profile.

Once anyone will click on chat button a popup window will appear. Now I want to detect dynamically if this popus is still open or closed.

If popup is opened= Display new message alert in notification.

if popup is closed = Do not alert new message in notification (As chat window is already opened)

This is what I tried:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="popitup("http://domain.com/chat/2")">Chat with user 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="popitup("http://domain.com/chat/1")">Chat with user 1</a>
```

```js
// on document ready
setInterval(function(){
    chkAlerts();
}, 10000);

var newwindow = null;

function popitup(url) {
    if ((newwindow == null) || (newwindow.closed)) {
        newwindow = window.open(url,'Buy','width=950,height=650,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
        newwindow.focus();
    } 
    else {
        newwindow.location.href = url;
        newwindow.focus();    
    }
}  

function chkAlerts(){
    if ((newwindow == null) || (newwindow.closed)) {
        //Do something
        alert('now window is closed show alerts');
    }
}
```

With this code I am always getting

```
alert('now window is closed show alerts');
```

Comment: Just so you know, when reloading or navigating away from the window-opener page, the reference to `newwindow` will be lost.

Comment: Yes jan, this is the actual problem, do you think is there any function in javascript to do this... or do i need play around with session or something?

Answer (score 0):

`chkAlerts` will always show the alert as the initial value of `newwindow` is `null`.

Presuming you only want the alert after a chat window has been closed tweak the logic to ignore the initial  `null` state;

```
function chkAlerts(){
    if ((newwindow != null) && (newwindow.closed)) {
        //Do something
        alert('now window is closed show alerts');
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not in the javascript code, is in the anchor, you are closing the double quotes inside the call to the function, they must be like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popitup('http://domain.com/chat/2')">Chat with user 2</a>
```

Anyway, but also, as you can see, you are only storing the last opened window, if your interest is in know that both are opened you should create newwindow as an array.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Continued from comments:

> Just so you know, when reloading or navigating away from the
>   window-opener page, the reference to newwindow will be lost.
>
> Yes jan, this is the actual problem, do you think is there any 
>   function in javascript to do this... or do i need play around with
>   session or something?

Not even possible with sessions or any other server sorcery.

Your option if you really need to keep track of the chat window is to include the chat on your "opener" page and make it an inline AJAX chat.

You could have an AJAX listener on all your pages and "open" that chat window on all open tabs/windows of your site, so that the user doesn't lose track of it.